# asp.net app javascript popup window doesn't display

Tags: javascript

My imagebutton will not cause the popup window to appear when its clicked. Here is my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToAddNewsletterAddPage() 
    {
        window.open("Newsletter.aspx","mywindow");
    }
</script>

    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="87px" Width="158px" ImageUrl="~/images/signup.gif" onclick="goToAddNewsletterAddPage()"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the console of the browser, you should see a syntax error. Function *declarations* (the style you've used in your script) **must** have a function name, so there's a syntax error...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //    ...v-- here
    function () 
    {
        window.open("Newsletter.aspx","mywindow");
    }
</script>
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToAddNewsletterAddPage() 
    {
        window.open("Newsletter.aspx","mywindow");
    }
</script>
```

(There is a different, but related, thing called a function *expression*, which doesn't have to have a function name [and due to [IE bugs](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) is usually better off without one], e.g.:

```
var x = function() { /* ... */ };
```

The key to knowing which is which is to look to see whether the `function` structure is being used as a *right-hand value*, e.g., the right-hand side of an assignment [`=`] or initializer [`:`], or being passed into a function as an argument. If it is, it's a function expression; if not, it's a function declaration.)